# Mix approach to create Autolayout constraints programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, visual-format-language

I am trying to create `Autolayouts` programmatically so I referred the [Autolayout Guide][1]. In which I found three techniques to programmatically create `Autolayouts`

1. Layout Anchors
2. NSLayoutConstraint Class
3. Visual Format Language

Regarding **Visual Format Language** `Autolayout Guide` Says:

> The notation emphasizes good visualization over completeness.
>   Therefore some constraints (for example, aspect ratios) cannot be
>   created using the visual format language.

Can I mix `Visual Format Language` with `Layout Anchors` to create other `constraints` with `Visual Format Language` and `Aspect ratio constraints` with `Layout Anchors`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course - once a layout constraint is created (by whatever means), it is a normal layout constraint.